# Is this PHP recursion nonsense?

Tags: php, recursion

This code represents some sort of recursion.

```
class Login implements Subject
{
    protected $observers = [];
    public function attach($observable)
    {
        if (is_array($observable)) {
            foreach ($observable as $observer) {
                $this->attach($observer);
            }
            return;
        }
        $this->observers[] = $observable;
        return $this;
    }
}

$login->attach([
    new LogHandler,
    new EmailNotifier
]);
```

I have three questions about this code:

1. `is_array($observable)` is executed for every single entry in the array `$observable`, right? Let's say the array `$observable` would have 100 entries. Would `is_array()` be executed 100 times, for every single array item?
2. How does `foreach` work here? It seems to jump out of the `foreach` loop and execute `attach()` and then return back to the loop until the end of the array is reached?
3. How does `return;` work here?

Either I don't get it, or this is a strange piece of code which makes no sense and includes unnecessary steps.

Comment: Answer for 1..3: use a debugger to see how it works. If you don't have a debugger at hand, put `echo()` statements before (and possibly after) each of the statements you are interested in, run the code then try to understand how it works based on the information it outputs. Adding an additional argument to the `attach()` method to track the nesting level (just for the purpose of debugging/understanding) helps a lot.

Comment: Your return does not matter, return itself just exists the function. but by returning the reference of the instance it allows for *chaining* (`$login->attach(new A)->attach(new B);`)

Answer (score 3):

It's not nonsense. It just provides a way to pass either a single, non-array value or an array of values. The `is_array()` check and recursive calls to `attach()` are how it decides whether (1) to add `$observable` itself when `$observable` is not an array or (2) to add each element of `$observable` when `$observable` is an array.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, if `$observable` is an array, then `is_array()` gets called once for `$observable` on the first call, then one more time for each element in the array. It may get called even more times if `$observable` contains nested arrays, like `[$obj1, [$obj2, $obj3]]`.
2. The `foreach` just loops over the array (that is, if `$observable` is an array). It attaches each element of `$observable`, then `return`s. It should probably return `$this` whether or not `$observable` is an array, both for consistency and to allow [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#PHP), like `$login->attach(new LogHandler)->attach(new EmailNotifier)->attach(new Foo);`. That said, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.
3. `return;` just exits the function. Again, it should probably be `return $this;` for consistency and to allow method chaining, but it's not doing anything special.

Comment: On 3, as I added in the comments of the OT, returning `$this` allows for chaining.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks; I edited my answer to clarify the value of this.